# Graphhopper flexible routing ignore street segment

Tags: graphhopper

I've read alot about flexible queries but unfortunatelly I couldn't find something satisfying yet.

I want the routing algorithm to ignore a street segmet, because its flooded or broken. Is that possible (maybe by putting geopoints into the GHRequest)? If it is, what is the best practice for the implementation?

---

update:
Do i need to create a custom Weighting and set the forbiddenEdges which i get out of OpenStreetMap.org?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a custom Weighting is currently necessary where you feed GraphHopper edgeIDs (!= OSM IDs). Get these edgeIDs via LocationIndex.findClosest.

Please create an issue if you want to have this via web API.